# How to find the exact error position/location in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

In an **PHP** array, if there is an error it returns only the line number.
But it will be difficult to find the location of error if the array contains large number of items. In this case how will I find the exact error position/location to save the time.
The error usually gives some hint.

*[Example]*
***Parse error:*** syntax error, unexpected 'S' (T_STRING), expecting ')'

But in the above case, there can be many strings in the array containg 'S'.
So is there an easy way to find it.

I also tried finding strings like ***""S*** or ***S""*** in Find and Replace of the editor, where the syntax is actually wrong so that I can find the error but this is not always the case.